# Maintaining CSS Hierarchy

Tags: css, asp.net, html

I have a HTML5 page which has a master css and tabbed layout. Some tabs have 3rd party controls (like bootstrap.css etc ) which gets loaded when that tab is clicked resulting in overriding some of the properties of styles set by master.css

We can solve this issue by not allowing those particular properties to NOT get overridden by !important. But we have 1000's of such properties and may not be possible to do it manually for all.

Any workaround for this?

Comment: Please add your code to the question. HTML and CSS

Comment: add a class or id to the parent so that it will on target if it has the class for parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in one of the comments, you can use something called as *CSS specificity* to solve the problem.
You can read more about it [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

To be brief, make the *more important styles* more specific.
For example:

```
.my-divs .green {
    color: green;
}
```

receives more priority then

```
.green {
    color: green;
}
```